# How to implement nested routing with react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want the header to be rendered when on the home page when the user navigates to `"/content"`, and when they navigate to  `"/content/about"`, the About page is rendered without a header. This does not happen. Can you tell me where my problem is?

`"/content"`:
Header
Home page by header

`"/content/about"`:
About page without header

App.js:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Content from "./Content";

const ByHeader = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>Header</div>
      <Content />
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/content">
          <ByHeader />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/content/*">
          <Content />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

and

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => {
  return <div>Home page by header</div>;
};

const About = () => {
  return <div>About page without header</div>;
};

const Content = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Route path="/" exact>
        <Home />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/about" exact>
        <About />
      </Route>
    </>
  );
};

export default Content;
```

[cosesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/routing-d0pyr8?file=/src/Content.js:0-420)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The code isn't working right now for a few reasons:

1. You are rendering all the routes, including the route that renders the header, into a single `Switch` component.
2. The route in the `Switch` that renders the header is listed first and once matched, the rest of the routes are ignored, matching or not.
3. The `Content` component is using absolute paths that don't include the `"content"` path segment from the parent route, so these routes are unmatchable.

## Suggested Solution

My suggestion would be to treat the `content` component more as a layout component that unconditionally renders the header on a route, and renders the route content conditionally within a `Switch` component.

Remember that all `Route` components alone are ***inclusively*** matched and rendered, e.g. anything that matches will be rendered, while `Route` components rendered within the `Switch` component are ***exclusively*** matched and rendered, e.g. the first matching `Route` or `Redirect` is rendered.

Also keep in mind that when using the `Switch` or passing an array of paths to the `Route` component that path order and specificity matters. Order the routes/paths in the ***inverse*** order of path specificity. For example, `"/content/about"` is more specific than `"/content"` is more specific than `"/"`, so this should be the order of the path when attempting to match.

Here's the implementation of my suggestion.

Example:

```
const Content = () => {
  const { path } = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <>
      <Route path={[path]} exact component={Header} />
      <Switch>
        <Route path={`${path}/about`} component={About} />
        <Route path={path} component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
};
```

The parent/App component

```
<Route path="/content" component={Content} />
```

### Demo

[image: Edit how-to-implement-nested-routing-by-react-router]

Answer (score 0):

Router.js

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // here you should have IsAuthorized in your services 
    // to check if user is authorized or not
    if (!IsAuthorized) {
      navigate('/image');
    }
  }, []);

  return children;
};

const Image =()=> {
  return (
    <div>
      <header> your header goes here </header>
      <div>Image page</div>
    </div>
  )
}

const ImageAbout =()=> {
  return (
    <div>
      <header> don't include header </header>
      <div>Image page</div>
    </div>
  )
}

export const  RootRouter = () => {

return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/"
        element={
          <PrivateRoute>
            <RootPage />
          </PrivateRoute>
        }
      >
        <Route path="/image/about" element={<Image/>} />
        <Route path="/image/about" element={<ImageAbout />} />
    </Route>
    </Routes>
}
```

Usage

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <RootRouter />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```